# Sort Vector3s by position on sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of Vector3s that are vertices on the surface of a sphere. I would like to sort these so they start at the South pole of the sphere and spiral up to the North pole.

I thought that you could sort the vertices by y, then subsort those by z and x, but I don't know how to implement this in c#.

Comment: See [this](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1381605/view.html), here is complete solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function is a [comparison method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=netframework-4.8) to compare two vectors you will be able to reference in the [`List.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) method

First of all, it compares if the vectors are the same.

Then, it compares the `y` components, and finally, compares the angle of the vector on the `(XZ)` plane.

```
public static int Compare( Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2 )
{
    // Comparing two vectors this way is fine
    // Unity has overloaded the == operator
    // So as to avoid floating point imprecision
    if ( v1 == v2 ) return 0;

    if ( Mathf.Approximately( v1.y, v2.y ) )
    {
        float magnitude1 = v1.magnitude;
        float magnitude2 = v2.magnitude;

        if ( Mathf.Approximately( magnitude1, 0 ) ) return -1;
        if ( Mathf.Approximately( magnitude2, 0 ) ) return 1;

        // I took opposite coordinates because I had
        // "better" results, meaning the "smallest" angle would be
        // associated to the vector closer to the (1,0,0) vector
        // with an anti clock-wise rotation
        float angle1 = Mathf.Atan2( -v1.z, -v1.x );
        float angle2 = Mathf.Atan2( -v2.z, -v2.x );
        if ( Mathf.Approximately( angle1, angle2 ) ) return 0;
        return angle1 > angle2 ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return v1.y > v2.y ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Here is a little snippet to add some gizmos to your scene view so as to see the vectors.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Vector3 origin = Vector3.zero;
        Gizmos.color = new Color( 1, 1, 1, 0.2f );
        for( int i = 0 ; i < Vectors.Count ; ++i )
        {
            Gizmos.DrawLine( origin, Vectors[i] );

            UnityEditor.Handles.Label( Vectors[i], i.ToString() );
            if( i < Vectors.Count - 1 )
                DrawGizmoArrow( Vectors[i], Vectors[i + 1], Color.HSVToRGB( (float) i / Vectors.Count, 1, 1 ) );
        }
    }

    private void DrawGizmoArrow( Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color )
    {
        if ( end == start ) return;
        Color c = Gizmos.color;
        Gizmos.color = color;
        Gizmos.DrawLine( start, end );
        Vector3 right = Quaternion.LookRotation( end - start ) * Quaternion.Euler(0, 180 + 20, 0) * new Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
        Vector3 left = Quaternion.LookRotation( end - start ) * Quaternion.Euler(0, 180 - 20, 0) * new Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
        Gizmos.DrawRay( end, right * 0.25f );
        Gizmos.DrawRay( end, left * 0.25f );
        Gizmos.color = c;
    }
#endif
```